# Child content is ignoring fit-content width defined by parent grid

Tags: css, grid

I have a card component that works with `display: grid` and I have defined 2 columns `fit-content(135px) 1fr`. On the first column (which should be 135px maximum) I have a component that has a child element that is not fitting into the column width and makes the column to go wider.

I've tried setting on the child node that causing the issue by placing `min-width: 0` and `max-width: 100%` and all combinations possible. The only working solution I found is set a `max-width` to the child node but that would break the component styling on the app.

I'm missing something?

This is the css code I have:

```
.grid {
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(135px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "selector title"
        "selector ."
 }

 .child {
     grid-area: selector;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(minmax(135px,1fr) 1fr);
```

Comment: I've tried but same result :(

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make Grid Column width fit-content row-wise.
But It is not possible.
The Column width is possibly to be `min-content` or `max-content` for using the large text or small to be a minimum width.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a"
    "b";
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
  grid-column: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
  
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1 x">Item1-----------</div>
  <div class="item2 x">Item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No changes after trying 